# gstreamer video streaming

Tags: java, video, streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

I have executed AudioPlayer.java example posted by open source community link

[Audio Player Tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/wiki/AudioPlayerTutorial)

I got the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such Gstreamer factory: playbin
 at org.gstreamer.ElementFactory.makeRawElement(ElementFactory.java:180)
 at org.gstreamer.Element.makeRawElement(Element.java:92)
 at org.gstreamer.elements.PlayBin.<init>(PlayBin.java:119)
 at org.gstreamer.example.AudioPlayer.main(AudioPlayer.java:56)
```

Can anyone give me the solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need change

```
PlayBin playbin = new PlayBin("AudioPlayer");
```

for

```
PlayBin2 playbin = new PlayBin2("AudioPlayer");
```

with the version 1.5

Answer (score 1):

This is due to path variables being not set correctly.

If you are using NetBeans 6.9+ then follow these steps

Note: I am assuming that you are working in Windows XP/Vista/7, etc.

1. Create a new project
2. Download gstreamer-java-1.4.jar and jna-3.2.4.jar
3. Add jna and jar files to library of the created NetBeans Project
4. Download GStreamer-WinBuilds-GPL-x86.msi from the following OSS website
   http://code.google.com/p/ossbuild/
   For commercial use their LGPL version.
   Make sure your environmental variable with prefix OSS_ is set in the environmental variables in Windows. You can access this by right clicking "My Computer" -> "Advanced"
5. In NetBeans Right click "project" -> "properties". Go to "VM Options" in "run"
   type

   ```
   -Djna.library.path="[your gstream OSS build classpath1 to bin]:[your gstream OSS build classpath2 to lib]"
   ```

   Similarly you may need to provide classpath to java here too

   ```
   -Djava.library.path="[your gstream OSS build classpath1 to bin]:[your gstream OSS build classpath2 to lib]"
   ```

   Note: You must know where your OSS gstreamer dlls are installed. Typically under "OSSbuild" directory in "Program Files".
6. You may have to reboot
7. Run and Enjoy Gstreamer!

Comment: I'm having issues with Java and GStreamer in that I have upgraded GStreamer for other uses and now the Java API won't work. How can I force the Java app to look at the Gstreamer 0.10 folders?

Comment: @Eddie Sanders You did not state which OS you are using. Is this Windows? It clearly states that GStreamer 0.10 is last compatible version as of today https://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/  I would try to see if any environment variables or symlinks (in case of linux) point to default gstreamer. On Ubuntu if one wants to choose a default version one can do 'sudo update-alternatives --config <name of the program>'.